# ¿ Es posible saber cuando rotas el móvil en Unity?

Tags: unity3d

¿ Sería posible hacer una determinada acción cuando rotas el móvil por ejemplo 90º ? Es decir, pones un objeto, un cubo y cuando giras el móvil, ese cubo se gire, es posible? y si Vuelves hacia atrás o al revés se vuelve a rotar hacia el otro lado.

Comment: Hola @RfMvs. Un gran número de tus preguntas recibieron respuestas y jamás las aceptaste... ¿Ninguna de esas tuvo una respuesta satisfactoria?

Comment: Respecto a tu pregunta: Si, es posible. En cuanto al *cómo*, deberías mostrar lo que has intentado, asi como lo que sucede: errores, problemas? Visita [ask] para saber como formular una buena pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Muchas de mis preguntas no tienen aceptación porque no logran lo que yo quiero, creo que aquí si no pones una aunque esté mal te echan la bronca, la única que puede que esté bien pero no la he aceptado (logicamente) es la de jorgesys de una que formulé pero no tengo android studio para comprobarlo. Y entonces sí Mariano, si no las acepto es que no son satisfactorias.

Comment: @RfMvs Gracias por la aclaración, y no es mi intención echar la bronca de nada. Las preguntas son tuyas para aceptar o dejar sin aceptación lo que quieras. Mi comentario simplemente apuntaba también a ayudarte a obtener las mejores respuestas posibles... Si puedo recomendarte algo, a veces es bueno dejar un comentario debajo de la respuesta recibida aclarando en qué específicamente es que no te resulta satisfactoria, no sólo como cortesía a quien se tomó el tiempo en responder, sino principalmente para que otros vean qué falta y puedan orientarse mejor para ver si pueden responderte.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Puedes acceder al giroscopio del dispositivo a través de [`Input`](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.html) usando [`Input.gyro`](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input-gyro.html) que devuelve al "gyroscope" por defecto, puede tratar algo asi:

script.cs

```
Gyroscope giro;

void Start () {

     giro = Input.gyro;

     if(!giro.enabled){
         giro.enabled = true;
     }
 }
```

y en update por ejemplo:

```
  void Update () {

      gameObject.transform.rotation  = giro.attitude;
  }
```

`giro.attitude` devuelve un Quaternion, que viene siendo la "attitude" es decir la orientacion en el espacio del dispositivo.

O puede tambien usar `giro.rotationRate` lo que retorna un `Vector3` que es la velocidad de rotación medida por el giroscopio que tiene el dispositivo.

Mira en [`Gyroscope`](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=Gyroscope) para más información.

---

En alguna parte de la documentacion unity dice algo asi:

> El Gyroscope es "right-handed" y Unity is "left handed"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con lo que puede usar algo asi en su codigo de ser necesario:

```
transform.rotation = HelperGyroToUnity(Input.gyro.attitude);// <-- aqui le pasa el Quaternion, asi o por ejemplo giro.attitude.

private static Quaternion HelperGyroToUnity(Quaternion q){
    return new Quaternion(q.x, q.y, -q.z, -q.w);
}
```

Comment: Como has dicho lo que yo quería, te doy el +1, tal como hago siempre que responden lo que satisface mi pregunta :) Gracias!

Comment: Lo que pasa Angel, eso detecta si voy hacia derecha puedo hacer **una acción** y si voy hacia la izquierda **hace otra accion** ?

Comment: Me refiero, he puesto lo que has puesto arriba y funciona, mi objeto rota, pero si giro para la izquierda que haga algo y si giro a la derecha que haga otra, accion eso es posible?

Comment: @RfMvs sus dos comentarios son algo confusos entre si, pero me imagino que con el segundo aclarara el primero, centrandome en el segundo, si entiendo bien, si, esto es posible con algo de codigo, pero necesito que ponga una pregunta para responderla, o intentarlo pues esta pregunta trata de una cosa y esto que menciona aun estando relacionado son preguntas distintas, y puede confundir quizas a futuros usiarios si lo pongo todo en la misma respuesta ect. Ademas sobre lo de girar dependiendo de lo que quiera tiene o puede usar una forma u otra. Saludos

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias, este finde abriré la pregunta, muchas gracias.